# How to set the Focus on Particular Cell in UI Grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid, angular-grid

I have a situation where, if I edit **`Cell1`**, UI Grid will run validators for **`Cell1`**, but I also want to run the validators for **`Cell2`**.
If **`Cell2`** value is not proper then I want to set focus on **`Cell2`** with validation message set in **`uiGridValidateService.setValidator()`**.

I am able to run the validator for **`Cell2`** on **`Cell1`** edit using below statement, but not able to highlight **`Cell2`**.

**Code:**

```
gridApi.grid.validate.runValidators(rowEntity, colDef, rowEntity['Cell2'], NaN, $scope.gridApi.grid);
```

**How can I put focus on a particular cell in UI Grid?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by below, hope it will help someone with same requirement,

Rather than trying to set the focus on error field, I just added below code on afterCellEdit().

```
if (!rowEntity['$$errors' + fieldName]) {
        rowEntity['$$errors' + fieldName] = {};
    }
    rowEntity['$$errors' + fieldName][validatorName] = true;
    rowEntity['$$invalid' + fieldName] = true;
```

Where my fieldName is target field which I want to get validated on every cellEdit. So in my case, even if I am editing value of Cell1, I will pass fieldName='Cell2' and it will get validated against my validator that I will pass as 'validatorName'. If it is not proper value then it will highlight cell2 as red and will show its tooltip.

Hope it will help someone. Let me know if any questions.